# Prove by induction that $n\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2 > (\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i)^2$

Tags: induction, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

How does one prove by induction that

$n \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2 > (\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i)^2$ for $(n \geq 2)$

Using a base case of $n = 2$, where all the $x_i$ may not equal each other.

I am aware that the [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) can be used taking all $y_i = 1$.
However the exercise I am trying to solve is asking to prove this using induction.

So far, for the base case $n = 2$ I have:

$2 \sum_{i=1}^{2}x_i^2 > (\sum_{i=1}^{2} x_i)^2$
$\Leftrightarrow  2 (x_1^2 + x_2^2)> (x_1 + x_2)^2$

$\Leftrightarrow  2x_1^2 + 2x_2^2> x_1^2 + 2x_1x_2 + x_2^2$
$\Leftrightarrow  (x_1 - x_2)^2 > 0$

This is true because $x_1 \neq x_2$.

For the inductive part I try to prove this for $n+1$. I have:

$(n+1) \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}x_i^2 > (\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} x_i)^2 $

$\Leftrightarrow (n+1) (x_{n+1}^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2) > (x_{n+1} + \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i)^2 $

I'm not entirely sure where to go further. The exercise suggests working with

$\sqrt{(n+1) (x_{n+1}^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2)}$
and
$ \left | x_{n+1} \right | + \left | \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i \right | \geq  \left | \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} x_i \right | $

Comment: Try going from $n$ to $2n$ and then $n$ to $n - 1$.

Comment: For noninduction, if you divide by $n^2$ and subtract you're looking at $\sigma^2>0$, i.e. the variance $\frac{1}{n}\sum (x_i - \frac{1}{n}\sum x_j)^2$ of the uniform distribution on $\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$ (or weighted if any $x_i$ is repeated).

Comment: @runway44 I suppose this makes sense, as this was a proof relating linear regression for   $R(a,b) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i - ax_i - b)^2$. I needed this for proving that the Hessian of $R$ is positive-definite under the assumption that not all $x_i$ are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding both sides, to prove
$$nx_{n+1}^2 + n\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2 + x_{n+1}^2 + \sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2 > x_{n+1}^2+ 2x_{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i + \left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)^2$$

- $n\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2 >\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)^2$ is the induction hypothesis,
- $x_{n+1}^2 = x_{n+1}^2$,
- then summing all $i = 1, \ldots, n$,

$$0 < \sum_{i=1}^n (x_{n+1}-x_i)^2 = nx_{n+1}^2 -2x_{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i + \sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2$$